# Application.Quit() does not seem to close the app on Hololens 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I have a unity app with HandMenu in the first scene. One of the buttons in this Menu is to kill/close the app.

I have made a script that has the following method and attached it to the button's Interactbale component's onClick() events.

`public void EndApplication(){ Application.Quit(); }`

It seems to be not working on Hololens 2.

Comment: Hm this should d it afaik (not in the editor but in a build). Can you confirm this is executed? I would add a log like `Debug.Log("####### QUITTING APPLICATION #####");` and see if this appears in your log file after hitting the button and then closing the app via the normal menu

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that the script which had the above function was destroyed in the second scene. Now it works when I added `DontDestroyonLoad()`.